# Installing snort on OS X

Tags: snow-leopard, security

I am on the lookout for an IDS/IPS solution for OS X 10.6. I tried compiling snort for 10.6 and I'm having trouble compiling a dependency, DAQ.

The error I get is:

```
mv -f .deps/daq_ipfw_la-daq_ipfw.Tpo .deps/daq_ipfw_la-daq_ipfw.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -DBUILDING_SO -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wsign-compare -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-strict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -module -export-dynamic -avoid-version -shared  -o daq_ipfw.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/daq daq_ipfw_la-daq_ipfw.lo ../sfbpf/libsfbpf.la -lpcap 
libtool: link: gcc -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup -o .libs/daq_ipfw.so -bundle  .libs/daq_ipfw_la-daq_ipfw.o   ../sfbpf/.libs/libsfbpf.dylib -lpcap   
libtool: link: dsymutil .libs/daq_ipfw.so || :
sed: 2/sfbpf/libsfbpf.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `2/sfbpf/libsfbpf.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[2]: *** [daq_ipfw.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

1. Any hints on how I can solve the problem?
2. Any links you can point me to where I can get a build for snort that works on OS X?
3. Any other IDS/IPS solutions you might point me to? Thanks!

Comment: Could you use macports (or homebrew or fink)? rather than do your own compile. Theses ports will have produced build scripts that work

Answer (score 2):

Use MacPorts. It's machine work to chase dependencies, not yours.